# Agora Interactive Live Video Streaming - How to enable audio on broadcaster side?

Tags: ios, swift, agora.io

https://docs.agora.io/en/Interactive%20Broadcast/start_live_ios?platform=iOS

I've followed above tutorial to implement interactive live video streaming. I've one broadcaster and multiple audience. Only broadcaster can broadcast and audience can only view broadcaster.

Broadcaster can't hear his own audio. Is there a way to enable audio on broadcaster side so that he can hear his own audio?

I've used code from above tutorial and set role to .broadcaster on broadcaster side and on audience side it is set to .audience.

Broadcaster

```
func setClientRole() {
    // Set the client role as "host"
    agoraKit?.setClientRole(.broadcaster)
}
```

Audience

```
func setClientRole() {
    // Set the client role as "audience"
    agoraKit?.setClientRole(.audience)
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Broadcaster can't hear his own audio.

Answer (score 1):

Generally with Video Streaming services the local user can not hear their own audio by design (look at YouTube Live, FB/Insta Live, etc). Otherwise it would cause echo or could possibly mute the audio if the echo cancelation. It is also very disorienting to a user to hear themselves so I would recommend against this.

In an effort to still answer your question and if it's imperative to your project to have that mic audio, I would recommend that you force the user to use headphones to avoid echo issues. This way you can use a custom audio source ([full guide](https://docs.agora.io/en/Interactive%20Broadcast/custom_audio_apple?platform=iOS#custom-audio-source)), where you initialize the mic and can send the audio to the headphones as well as pass it to the Agora SDK.

Since the implementation end of this could vary greatly depending on your project, I'll explain the basic concept.

With Agora you can enable the custom audio source using:

```
self.agoraKit.enableExternalAudioSource(withSampleRate: sampleRate, channelsPerFrame: channel)
```

When you join the channel you would initialize the mic yourself, and maintain that buffer. Then pass the custom audio to the

```swift
self.agoraKit.pushExternalAudioFrame(buffer, System.currentTimeMillis());
```

For more details I'd recommend taking a look at [Agora's API Examples Project](https://github.com/AgoraIO/API-Examples/blob/master/iOS/APIExample/ViewController.swift). You can use some of the [Audio Controllers](https://github.com/AgoraIO/API-Examples/tree/master/iOS/APIExample/Common/ExternalAudio) to see how the audio is handled.